# Unable to Get and Set Extract from File Name - regexextract() with getName()

Tags: google-apps-script

1st time posting; pretty green in scripting; striking out all over the place trying to find a solution to the following that I'm guessing is elementary...

In a G-Sheet, I'm needing to create a list of all the files in a G-Drive folder. Each file is to be labeled in this list by an item # that's included in each file's name; these item #s follow a consistent character pattern (e.g. AB123A) that can be described by regex '[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]'. Files may be named as such:

```
"Merch Bin 1 - CC554A - 3.15.20"
"AB101C - Web"
```

I've started with the following script to sequentially get the file names from the folder and set in column 1 of the 1st empty row, but I'm unable to figure out how to modify it to extract just the item # from the file name & set it accordingly:

```
function listitems(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(‘Folder ID');
 var contents=folder.getFiles();
 var file;
 var item;
 while(contents.hasNext()){
    file=contents.next();
    item=file.getName(); //Assume this is where to apply any regex extract functionality to extract the item # from the file name
    ss.appendRow([item]); //Intended to set item #'s extracted from file names to col.1 of 1st empty row
 }
}
```

Any help & direction is appreciated.

Comment: You are really close to the final answer.  Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) you can probably find the solution in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So starting from your matching condition that you're suggesting: `[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]`

you'll need to declare a new variable: `var re =new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]");`

After looping through the files you check your condition:

`if(item.match(re)){output.push([item, link])};`

With the following script you'll be able to choose which folder to list the files from, and likewise choose in which sheet to write the data.

**Code:**

```
// Create a menu to run the script
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('List Files')
    .addItem('Go!', 'listMyFiles')
    .addToUi();
}

function listMyFiles() {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID GOES HERE');
  var sheetId = "SHEET ID GOES HERE";

  //Set up spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);

  // specify the name of the sheet to write the DATA  

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var re =new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]");

  sheet.getRange("A2:B").clear();

  var output = [];
  var file;
  var item;
  var link;
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();    
    data = [
      item =  file.getName(),
      link =  file.getUrl(),
    ];
    if(item.match(re)){
    output.push([item, link]);
    }
    // write data to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }  
};
```

Your Sheet will be similar to this:

[image]

the script has 'ignored' the other files and brought only the ones matching the condition.

Comment: Hey thanks so much, Nabnub! While I've got a separate copy sheet replicating your script & operating as demonstrated, what's needed yet is for just the item #s listed in column A (AB101C & CC554A); not the full file name. I recognize that I can just add a helper column with a =regexextract() formula to pull out the item #s, but I'm pretty bent on learning how to do it on the script side. Hope I'm not missing something in your example that accomplishes what I'm getting after. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, if the solution did answer your initial question, please consider accepting as a Correct Answer by ticking. You could use a formula to do that, or try with few more lines in the code. Give it a try by searching a little bit, otherwise you won't learn much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, seem to have got it figured out to the best of my limited ability with the help of yalls direction...

By adding the execute function to line 18 (re.exec(filename);) the script is successfully extracting the regex-defined item # from the file name and writing it to the designated range (A2 + down).

```
function listitems(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var re=new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]");
 var output=[];

//CLEAR RANGE
 var listrange=ss.getRange("A2:O")
 listrange.clearContent();

//SET FILE LIST
 var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(‘Folder ID');
 var contents=folder.getFiles();
 var file;
 var item;
 while(contents.hasNext()){
    file=contents.next();
    filename=file.getName();
    item=re.exec(filename);
    output.push([item]);

    ss.getRange(2,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
 }
}
```

My next obsession is figuring out how to link the item # cells to their corresponding file on the scripting side as opposed to writing both the item # and file URL to the sheet then applying a =hyperlink() formula, so I'll explore for those tips outside of this post.

Cheers

Comment: Well that's easy, you just need to declare a new variable: `var HyperLink ;` and likewise `var link;`. Then just before the `output.push([item]);` you add this line `HyperLink =  '=HYPERLINK(\"' + link + '\",\"' + item + '\")'`.

Comment: Although it's already mentioned in my answer, you also have in your loop `link =  file.getUrl()`